# Publishing DFS replication to a Namespace

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, windows-server-2012-r2, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I'm creating a chef cookbook which runs on 2 Windows boxes

- Turns on DFS Windows feature
- Creates a folder and sets it up for replication
- Creates a Replication Group and registers it to the ActiveDirector

The recipes are calling PowerShell commands to automate these tasks. This is working well.

What I still need to to is creating a Namespace and Publishing the replication in that Namespace.

Based on [this](https://windorks.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/dfs-namespace/) tutorial, I managed to do it in no time with the DFS Management UI.

I need a way to do it with PowerShell or with anything what I can call from Chef.

Note: If I can publish the replication to an already existing Namespace, that's already a half solution for me.

Update: I'm using Windows 2012 R2. ( The latest version provided on AWS.)

Comment: Which Windows version are your servers running?

Comment: I'm using Windows 2012 R2. ( The latest version provided on AWS.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Server 2012 R2 you can use the [DFS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj884270.aspx) [cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296591.aspx) for DFS administration.

```
$path   = '\\server\share'
$domain = 'example.org'
$ns     = 'mynamespace'
$group  = 'RGroup'
$name   = 'myreplicatedfolder'

New-DfsnRoot -TargetPath $path -Type DomainV2 -Path "\\$domain\$ns"
New-DfsReplicatedFolder -GroupName $group -FolderName $name `
  -DfsnPath "\\$domain\$ns\$name"
```

I don't have access to a DFS environment right now, but somthing like the above should work.